# Get coordinates of event in textBox or TextArea?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I listen to the text box (`textarea`) key-down event, can I get the coordinates of event when user type any characters into it?

```
$('#textAreaId').bind('keydown', function(event) {    
    var data = event.originalEvent.touches ? event.originalEvent.touches[0] : event;
    alert(data.pageY);    
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want the position of the element or the position of the caret?

To get the position of the caret you can use the following function (borrowed from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-cursor-position-in-textarea)):

```
function getCaret(el) { 
  if (el.selectionStart) { 
    return el.selectionStart; 
  } else if (document.selection) { 
    el.focus(); 

    var r = document.selection.createRange(); 
    if (r == null) { 
      return 0; 
    } 

    var re = el.createTextRange(), 
        rc = re.duplicate(); 
    re.moveToBookmark(r.getBookmark()); 
    rc.setEndPoint('EndToStart', re); 

    return rc.text.length; 
  }  
  return 0; 
}
```

To get the position of the `textarea` element relative to the document, you use [`.offset`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/):

```
$("#textAreaId").bind('keydown', function(event){
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    console.log(offset);
});
```

I put up a [test case on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/7YDkG/).

Comment: Yes I olredy see code like this. But I try to get the exact coordinates of cursor in textArea from the top of the window. That's would be perfect solution.

Comment: @Darien, for the cursor or the caret?

Comment: Need x/y coordinates of caret it textArea.

Comment: @Darien, sadly it's not possible to do that with the `textarea` element. Here's a working solution involving an offscreen `span` element: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059254/current-x-y-coordinates-of-cursor-in-text-area-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

[Caret position in textarea, in characters from the start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-cursor-position-in-textarea)

Comment: How to get cursor position in textarea from the top of window?