# Get (x,y) coordinates of cursor while typing in text area

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display something e.g div under text area where user typing

I managed to obtain where he's currently typing via `selectionStart/End`, but how can I actually calculate coordinates (x,y) of his cursor?

I suppose there are other ways of achieving that than these two:

1. Calculating in which row user is (based on font size, text area width and characters count in that text area).
2. x as `textarea.X + selectionStart` in this row
   y as `textarea.Y + rows * font size`

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059254/current-x-y-coordinates-of-cursor-in-text-area-using-javascript), but it is almost 10 years old

Comment: What's wrong with the algorithms you've suggested?

Comment: @GalAbra I don't there's something wrong with it (except it may be tricky with "weird" characters) but I thought that it's already built in e.g in browser because it has to display those characters somehow...

Comment: Then you have an alternative solution in the post you've attached. It still works, 10 years later ;)

Comment: Having played around with the `cols` property, I think the 10 year old solution is the best way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/Codecademy/textarea-helper

```js
$('textarea').on('keyup paste cut mouseup', function () {
  // Get the textarea's content height.
  var contentHeight = $(this).textareaHelper('height')
  // Set the textarea to the content height. i.e. expand as we type.
  $(this).height(contentHeight);
  
  // Follow the caret arounbd.
  $('.tail').css(
    $(this).textareaHelper('caretPos')
  );
});

// Call it manually at first. 
$('textarea').keyup();
```

```css
.tail {
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

textarea {
  width: 250pxpx;
  min-height: 100px;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/Codecademy/textarea-helper/master/textarea-helper.js"></script>

<textarea></textarea>
<div class="tail"></div>
```

Comment: Related answer to this implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29709/how-do-i-get-the-x-y-pixel-coordinates-of-the-caret-in-text-boxes